# How to do an ajax post, from javascript, to a web-api service

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a logging method, that works on all my javascript calls.
It is not going too well. I get the following error:

> No action was found on the controller 'Log' that matches the request.

I have the following code, on my controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public void Post(string msg)
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataClassesDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyViewDkConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                ctx.UserInputInsert(msg, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
            }
        }
```

VERY simple. I am a bit unsure if it my routing that is the problem. Basically, I just have the default route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

To post the data, I'm using this javascript:

```
function Log(msg) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Log/",
        data: msg,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

So obviously, I'm doing something wrong. It is probably my routing, but I can't seem to solve it. I have tried changing the msg argument on the controller, to id, but it's still the same.

Comment: I notice you are applying the `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` action filter to your Post action. This is wrong and not needed. The `System.Web.Mvc` namespace is for MVC controllers, while the `System.Web.Http` namespace is for Web Api controllers. Similar names, but completely different. Are you positive your controller is a Web Api controller?

Comment: @Brett, yea it's a web api controller. I actually put the httppost there myself, I guess I hit the wrong namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been googling around for a while now, and I stumbled upon this article:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

It turns out, web Api doesn't really like it when you post a primitive value, like a string. To get it to work, you need to add `[FromBody]`to the parameter and also have a blank value name, when posting.

So, I have changed my code around a bit, and it now looks like this, and works.

Javascript:

```
function Log(msg) {
    $.post("/api/Log", { "": msg });
}
```

And my controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataClassesDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyViewDkConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                ctx.UserInputInsert(value, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
            }

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you - however, I have never had a problem using primitive types in the WebAPI hence my answer. These sort of problems are generally down to routing.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that has worked for me in the past...
You may possibly consider changing your mapping to include the controller action

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Then change your url in the ajax method to [controller]/[method]/. You would also need to define your post data argument.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/Log/Post/", //--'Log' being the Controller, 'Post' being the method
    data: JSON.stringify({"msg":msg}),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
});
```

Hope that helps. Keep us posted!

Comment: I would try avoid this as this starts to stray away from a REST-style architecture. The url shouldn't contain any sort of indicator to what type of operation it is (which is more CRUD style), all that should be ascertained by the request header information.

Comment: You are correct in regard to not adhering to REST. What I cannot ascertain from the question is whether REST is desired architecture that is being used. If so, wouldn't you also need to pass the host address in order to adhere to the stateless nature of REST? Curious as to your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: @bphillips, I definitely want to stick to REST.